# unable to add/remove program in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: software-center, gnome-terminal, software-sources

**

my problem is as following:
unable to add/remove any program using either update-manager or Synaptic Package Manager or terminal

1. update-manager is asking for partial upgrade and  while updating
   software-center 5.2.6 catalog ,
   there is no progress beyond the line "**this is may take a moment**"
2. synaptic is unable to obtain an exclusive lock,
   similarly can't do terminal command
   **sudo apt-get update**
3. if i try to break down the lock using the command

   **sudo fuser -cuk /var/lib/dpkg/lock; 
   sudo rm -f /var/lib/dpkg/lock**

   it turns off my monitor display and i have to restart the whole system.

   note: this whole trouble started ,when i found ubuntu software-center missing after   adding a repository and reinstalled it.

**

Comment: can i update software catalog any other way?

Answer (score 0):

The parameters of `fuser` are wrong. The `-c` option is an alias for `-m` option that select the whole filesystem of the path and the `-k` parameter kill all processes the own that filesystem (see 
[fuser man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fuser) for reference). So, with this command **you kill all system** except the kernel.

Use this command for get the pid (and user) of the process the use the dpkg database:

```
$ sudo fuser -u /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Example output:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/lock:  14502(root)
```

You can kill it (if you know what you're doing) with:

```
$ sudo kill -9 14502
```

For remove the lock only use:

```
$ sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
```

Comment: i used command '$ sudo kill -9 1737'                           and got this after running update **E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.**'$ sudo dpkg --configure -a' **Setting up software-center (5.2.6) ... Updating software catalog...this may take a moment.** INFO:softwarecenter.db.pkginfo_impl.aptcache:aptcache.open()

Comment: Ok, you have interrupted dpkg during software-center upgrading. With `sudo dpkg --configure -a` you have finished upgrading. All done.